# npm start Error: Cannot find module 'C:\' and Exit status 8

Tags: node.js, npm, package-managers

I have a little NPM challenge for you.

Tech. info:

- OS: Windows 7

I'm trying to:

cd to the project folder --> run npm start, "start" is configured in the package.json as "node ."

I get the following error:

```
**** npm start Error: Cannot find module 'C:\'
**** Exit status 8
**** the npm-debug.log look like the below:

    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]
    2 info using npm@1.3.24
    3 info using node@v0.10.25
    4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
    5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
    6 info prestart tile-tease-api@0.1.0
    7 info start tile-tease-api@0.1.0
    8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    9 info tile-tease-api@0.1.0 Failed to exec start script
    10 error tile-tease-api@0.1.0 start: `node .`
    10 error Exit status 8
    11 error Failed at the tile-tease-api@0.1.0 start script.
    11 error This is most likely a problem with the tile-tease-api package,
    11 error not with npm itself.
    11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    11 error     node .
    11 error You can get their info via:
    11 error     npm owner ls tile-tease-api
    11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    12 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
    14 error cwd "FOLDER OF PROJECT - EDITED"
    15 error node -v v0.10.25
    16 error npm -v 1.3.24
    17 error code ELIFECYCLE
    18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

During my troubleshooting I have found:

- It seems to have something to do with the invoking path. As I have no problems if I do
  **** instead of "node ." in the start definition in the package.json file I define the actual path
  **** or if i execute "node ." in a cmd directly instead of doing it through the "npm start" command.

The issue is that I'm sharing the project between other developers and they are developing on Mac's. On their setup it works with the start "node ."....and it would be cumbersome to have different package.json file and would beat the purpose of using Git.....

Have anyone bumped into this problem before and have any ideas for what I can do to overcome this.

Comment: it looks like it's failing on the "prestart" phase (not "start") where it tries to run the tile-tease-api script.  In constrast, when you run "node ." from the cli, it doesn't run the prestart.  So you might have a environment issue to resolve the tile-tease-api path.  Note: I tried the "node ." in a "start" field and it works on my Win7 machine.

Comment: Hi smertrios,

Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions to what that environement issue might be caused by?

Again, thank you!

Comment: where is the tease-tile-api coming from? part of your git checkout? or is it a toolchain/system tool (pre-installed)? looking at package.json , what's the "prestart" configured as? (try running its content from the cli)

Comment: hi smertrios :-)

There is no prestart in my package.json, it has not been configured. So nothing to run from the cli. The tile-tease-api is a private API I made.

Anything else I can inform you about in order for us to solve this :-)

Comment: I don't think the issue is with npm but rather with the tile-tease-api.  is it a script? does it have dependencies it can't resolve? just my 2 cents...

Comment: Hi Smertrios,

All dependencies can be resolved. When you say script what do you mean? It is a node js program.

Comment: @smertrios - this is still an issue - do you have any ideas? :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in node.js core, and it might have something to do with the fact that `require()` doesn't accept "." as a local path.

Try to write `node ./` instead.

Comment: Hi Alex,

I tried but got the below error:
----

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

npm ERR! tile-tease-api@0.1.0 start: `node ./`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tile-tease-api@0.1.0 start script.
----

other suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is still a problem I experience. Anyone else with a suggestion? Let me know :-) - any help is appreciated!